# How to check if the SYSTEM_VERSIONING for a table is ON?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ddl, data-versioning

I know that SQL Server 2016 let us to use the SYSTEM_VERSIONING like :

```
CREATE TABLE EmpSalary  
(    
     EmpID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , SalaryAmt decimal (10,2) NULL  
   , SalaryBeginDT datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL  
   , SalaryEndDT datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL  
   , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SalaryBeginDT, SalaryEndDT)     
)    
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

Also to deactivate this, it is only necessary to ALTER the table:

```
ALTER TABLE EmpSalary SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
```

My question is how to check if the SYSTEM_VERSIONING for a table is ON and then ALTER the table?

Answer (score 8):

You could query `sys.tables`

```
ALTER TABLE EmpSalary SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = On );
select name, temporal_type, temporal_type_desc from sys.tables where name = 'EmpSalary'

| name      | temporal_type | temporal_type_desc              |
|-----------|---------------|---------------------------------|
| EmpSalary | 2             | SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE |
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE EmpSalary SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
select name, temporal_type, temporal_type_desc from sys.tables where name = 'EmpSalary'

| name      | temporal_type | temporal_type_desc |
|-----------|---------------|--------------------|
| EmpSalary | 0             | NON_TEMPORAL_TABLE |
```

Comment: @eandbsoftware - if I have sufficiently answered your question, consider [accepting it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could check its [OBJECTPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): TableTemporalType.

The following code will perform a logical check to see if it is a Temporal Table, and if so, deactivate System Versioning.

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('EmpSalary'), 'TableTemporalType') = 2
    ALTER TABLE EmpSalary SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
```