# How to check if a table is system versioned for MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, temporal-tables, data-versioning

How to check if a table is system versioned for MariaDB ?

This post refers to same question on "SQL Server 2016"

[How to check if the SYSTEM_VERSIONING for a table is ON?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218517/how-to-check-if-the-system-versioning-for-a-table-is-on)

I've tried this syntax on MariaDB, but I got error.

I guess "TableTemporalType", is MS specific

(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 )

Anyone knows how can be done in MariaDB ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TABLE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database_name
  AND TABLE_NAME = table_name;
```

Comment: Would you care to mention what value of `TABLE_TYPE` indicates the system versioned table?

Comment: @Akina,
Thank you.
I just had to put database_name and table_name under quotes so it will work.
Also for who asked, the TABLE_TYPE came out be to "SYSTEM VERSIONED" (instead of "BASE TABLE").